# Anchor token replace patterns to the end of tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

according to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) this should not be possible

> Regular expressions cannot be anchored to the beginning or end of a token

nevertheless it seems to work for me

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "(dog)$",
      "replacement": "hot$1"
    }
  ],
  "text": "dog dogs"
}
```

returns

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "hotdog",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "dogs",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the pattern is anchored to the end of the token and "dog**s**" is not replaced because it doesn't end with "dog".

So my question is: Am I missing something or am I safe to use it (and the docs are just wrong)?

Comment: great finding, hv raised a bug, and fixed docs locally, once someone at elatic confirm, it will be fixed soon on site docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's the wrong documentation, and [Elasticsearch bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/64173) for this, have looked at the elastic code, and **there is no special handling of the beginning or end of the token**.

Please refer to [this ES code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/modules/analysis-common/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/analysis/common/PatternReplaceTokenFilterFactory.java#L52) which is used for this token filter, it calls the Lucene token filter, and both at Elastic and Lucene code level there is no special handling.

Comment: @Raphael glad it helped :)

Comment: @Raphael fyi, my PR is also merged, so soon you will not see the confusing statement on ES website

Comment: @ Elasticsearch Ninja, you are indeed a ninja :)

Comment: @Raphael haha, thanks for your kind words, FYI, if you look at the master branch doc, you will see the correct doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html